# uniquewith returns a single element from the first array loadash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I have an

```
let obj = [{Id: "C87408"}, {Id: "C87402"}, {Id: "C87409"}]
let obj2 = [{Id: "C874018"}, {Id: "C87412"}, {Id: "C87419"}]
```

Here I am trying to use the uniqwith to remove the duplicate elements if any.

So, the way I have used is ,

```
let final = _.uniqWith([...obj, ...obj2], node => node.id)
```

Here it is returning me only one element which is `{Id: "C87408"}`

So, why this can be happening ?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your expected output from the two array of objects that you're using?

Comment: it should be if not duplicate then the concatenated result or else should remove the duplicate element and then concatenated result

Answer (score 2):

Your comparator function is incorrect: it should by using two arguments so that it can compare two separate nodes:

```
(a, b) => a.Id === b.Id
```

See proof-of-concept example:

```js
let obj = [{Id: "C87408"}];
let obj2 = [{Id: "C87408"}, {Id: "C99999"}];

let final = _.uniqWith([...obj, ...obj2], (a, b) => a.Id === b.Id);

console.log(final);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Update**: As others have pointed out in the comments, you can also use `_.uniqBy` for a shorter alternative:

```js
let obj = [{Id: "C87408"}];
let obj2 = [{Id: "C87408"}, {Id: "C99999"}];

let final = _.uniqBy([...obj, ...obj2], 'Id');

console.log(final);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Or use [`_.uniqBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy): `_.uniqBy([...obj, ...obj2], node => node.Id)`.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Oh yes, that, too :)